# batch file to copy newest file, then delete the original file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to create a batch file that finds the newest file in a directory, copies it to a new directory, then deletes the original. Everything works except for the delete portion. Here's what I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off
set source="C:\BLEND2\Results\LCBlend"
set target="z:\Blenders"
set NewestFile=

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:-D /B') 
DO set NewestFile=%%I
COPY %source%\"%NewestFile%" %target%
del %source%\%NewestFile%
```

Comment: any errormessages would be greatly appreciated. Probably `del "%source%\%newestfile%"` would solve it.

Comment: This was an error that needed fixing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `DO` needs to be on the same line as your closing parenthesis, also your code will retrieve the oldest file not the newest.

Try this altered version which uses `Move` instead of `Copy` followed by `Delete`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "source=C:\BLEND2\Results\LCBlend"
Set "target=Z:\Blenders"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/A-D/OD "%source%"') Do Set "NewestFile=%%A"
Move "%source%\%NewestFile%" "%target%"
```

Comment: The move worked. I never thought of trying that! Sometimes I get so caught up in the code, I don't think about the simple solutions. There were some other small syntax errors, but after fixing them, it seems to be doing what I need. Thanks for the help!